# Brand of mouse or keyboard with Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there any way to detect the brand of the mouse connected to the computer, or the brand of the keyboard connected to the pc? I have heard that mouse or keyboard does not have serial numbers but I may have heard incorrectly.

My main goal is to find out when the mouse and/or the keyboard
of the computer is changed with another. I am using visual c++. Is there any way to detect in visual c++ program
that the commonly used mouse or keyboard at a computer is substituted with another?

I am using Visual C++ 6.0.

Comment: `I am using Visual C++ 6.0` Don't, it's 18 years old and very outdated. And your question has no universal yes/no answer.

Comment: I have no choice with Visual C++. My computer is quite old, that is the reason.

Comment: Btw., there are things like usb locks etc. . If there is a problem with people taking low cost equipment, that's better than half-working software.

Comment: @citroen it would be better to use any other compiler, including gcc on cygwin, as the VS6.0 wasn't compliant to standards at the time - and you'll end up walking into issues that have been long since resolved.

Answer (score 3):

There's a fairly good chance that you can, yes.

You can get information about the mouse and keyboard by enumerating devices of the [`Win32_Keyboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394166.aspx) and [`Win32_PointingDevice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394356.aspx) classes using WMI.

I'd ignore (for example) the Mouse's "Manufacturer" field, which reflects the driver rather than the hardware (e.g., on the machine I'm using at the moment, it says "Microsoft", but the mouse is actually a Logitech).

You probably stand a better chance of getting accurate information by looking at the PnP device ID. This may not be 100% foolproof (see below), but on this machine the Vendor ID part of the PnP device ID contains "046D", which accurately maps to Logitech.

As to this not being foolproof, I can see a couple of possibilities. One would be a buy-out, where one company bought another, and sold existing stock of hardware under the new label without changing its Vendor ID. In this case, you might be able to replace one mouse from brand X with another (currently) sold by brand X, but the PnP device IDs would still show them as coming from different vendors.

In the other direction, I can imagine the possibility of a mouse vendor shipping mice with the vendor ID set to that of whoever made the USB interface chip, instead of getting a vendor ID of their own. In this case, you could have two mice with different brand labels on the outside, but the same vendor ID on the inside. A vendor could also build two mice with the same brand, but different interface chips, so you could get a false positive, showing different brands even though the packaging showed them as the same brand.

Oh, one other possibility: at least some vendors have more than one Vendor ID. Hewlett Packard (for one example) has at least two under its own name (and, one under the Compaq name, lending at least some credence to the first scenario above).

I honestly don't know how likely any of those is to arise in practice though. At a guess, they're probably particularly likely at the extremes--really low-end or really high-end hardware. Mainstream hardware is likely to be a lot more stable.

In any case, I think this is probably about the best you can do via software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do you think that WMI can be used with Visual C++ 6.0? I mean, in the link for Win32_Keyboard it is writted below : Minimum Supported client - Windows Vista , and i am using Windows XP?

Comment: Yes, WMI works fine with VC++6 on Windows XP (I've personally used that exact combination).